# MonoDevelop "The compiler appears to have crashed. Check the build output pad for details."

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have MonoDevelop 2.4.2, MonoTouch 3.2.6 and XCode 3.2.6.

In MonoDevelop, whenever I have a syntax error, the only error I have in my error list is "The compiler appears to have crashed. Check the build output pad for details.".  The build log does contain the actual compiler errors so I am able to fix them and get a successful compilation.  However, my coworker demonstrated that his compiler does *not* crash and the compiler errors listed in the build log actually are parsed and displayed in the error list window.  Also his MonoDevelop IDE then displays the message bubbles pointing out the errors in the code.  Mine does not do this.

Does anyone know how I can get the compiler to quit crashing and the IDE to be able to parse the errors and warnings from the build log like normal?

Comment: Could you provide a sample solution that exhibits this problem?

Comment: I had a similar error report (compiler crash - not sure if the cause is similar) and I posted my sample solution here: https://github.com/briandonahue/MonoIssue and my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607103/rhinomocks-breaking-the-compiler-in-recent-versions-of-mono-monodevelop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered the problem.  The path in which I had my source code stored had parenthesis.  When I pulled down source code from another repository into a path on my system without parenthesis, I got compiler errors in the list instead of just a compiler crash.  I confirmed this was the problem by relocated the other source code that I was having the problem with.

This also solved another one of my issues.  When I was adding files, the path in the .csproj file would be relative paths but they would go up several levels and back down messing it up for the next developer.  (So instead of having Views/file.cs I'd have ../../../MySourceCodeRoot/Application/Project/Views/file.cs or something close to that.)  Adding files with my source code root renamed without parenthesis works correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Send the error to monotouch support team
May be they can help you.
May be you have installed all the staff not in the right order